# Functional Tests with TYPO3 v10 no composer autoload

Tags: testing, composer-php, phpunit, typo3, autoload

When I try to run a functional test which uses the class TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Tests\Functional\SiteHandling\AbstractTestCase I get an error Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Tests\Functional\SiteHandling\AbstractTestCase' not found.... Is this an composer autoloader problem? Any Ideas how to fix this?

```
/usr/bin/php7.4 /mypath/typo3_10/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap /mypath/typo3_10/vendor/typo3/testing-framework/Resources/Core/Build/FunctionalTestsBootstrap.php --configuration /mypath/typo3_10/vendor/typo3/testing-framework/Resources/Core/Build/FunctionalTests.xml /mypath/typo3_10/web/typo3/sysext/seo --teamcity
```

is the command in PHPStorm.

Comment: Please share more details. Have you checked whether the class exists? Whether any autoloader is used?

Answer (score 0):

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Tests\\": "web/typo3/sysext/frontend/Tests/",
        "TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Tests\\": "web/typo3/sysext/core/Tests/"
    }
}
```

the solution is to add the missing Namespaces to the root composer.json and dump the autoloader again